# Creating jquery tab without any id or class

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a tab with this structure but could not get it done

Here is my code , I have ui with same structure

```js
$('.accoidian_cus_open h3').each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass('naccordion' + (i + 1));
});
$(".accoidian_cus_open h3").nextUntil(".accoidian_cus_open h3", "p").hide();
$(".accoidian_cus_open h3").click(function() {
  var nxt = $(this).closest("h3");
  // $(this).next
  $(this).nextUntil(nxt, "p").show();

})
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accoidian_cus_open">
  <h3>tab1</h3>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <h3>tab2</h3>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <h3>tab3</h3>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think `closest` may be getting in the way.  Closest looks for the closest ancestor of the type.  You might look at `siblings()` which provides a list of elements at the same level as the target.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nextuntil, you can use nth-child to hide all paragraph tags except for the first one.

Then use simple `parent` and `find`/ `next` tags along with `this` for hiding/showing on click.

```js
$('.accoidian_cus_open h3').each(function(i) {
  $(this).addClass('naccordion' + (i + 1));
});

$(".accoidian_cus_open p:nth-child(n+4)").hide();
$(".accoidian_cus_open h3").click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find("p").hide();
  $(this).next("p").show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accoidian_cus_open">
  <h3>tab1</h3>
  <p>tab1 content</p>
  <h3>tab2</h3>
  <p>tab2 content</p>
  <h3>tab3</h3>
  <p>tab3 content</p>
</div>
```